# Adding a backend web api to an existing game server program

Tags: c#, rest, https, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a program that runs a game server and wants to add Restful API to it to allow other platforms (web and mobile) to interact with the game server. I am having a difficult time making asp.net core web API work.
Are there other options besides .net core web API? I need something simple. I already have ef core store information about the players I just want to accept https request.

For those wondering which game server it is, it's GTA V Rage multiplayer game server with a custom script running.

I will try to provide additional information if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many options and languages available for REST API development. I'd suggest defining your API independently of the development language using OpenAPI. Have a look at Swagger at https://swagger.io/ and OpenAPI at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/.

Swagger also has tools available that generate an implementation of the REST API from your OpenAPI definition (stubs for client and server in your preferred language), see https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/.

The nice thing is that you can develop your REST API documentation at the same time. Have a look at the Swagger pet store example here: https://petstore.swagger.io/

Comment: Sorry I did not mention I want the language to be c# since that is the language the game server code is using. Swagger looks okay but I don't want documentation or auto generated code I am looking for a light weight rest api framework